# Calculating inactive time of a widget factory

Tags: python, time-series

I'm looking to see if anyone has an efficient idea for calculating the time where my widget factory was not in use. Let's imagine it fires up at t = 2 and runs until t = 55. I also can measure when widgets are making their way down the conveyor belt.

For example w1 = (3,8) and w2 = (5,11) and w3 = (20,30). Here, the belt was inactive between 2 and 3; 11 and 20; and 30 to 55. Note that multiple widgets can be on the belt at the same time (in this example, w1 and w2 shared some time overlapped).

So far, my efforts involved using sets to make unique integer increments of the total machine time and each of the widget's times, and then using set subtraction/difference() to arrive at the above answer. This doesn't feel very satisfactory given the continuous nature of time. Any thoughts?

```
factory = (2,55)
w1 = (3,8)
w2 = (5,11)
w3 = (20,30)

def unused(factory: tuple, widgets: list):
    factory_time = set(range(factory[0], factory[1]))
    unused_time = factory_time.copy()
    for widget in widgets:
        unused_time = unused_time - set(range(widget[0], widget[1]))
    return unused_time

unused(factory, [w1, w2, w3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[intspan](https://intspan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) could be adapted to give total idle time.

I don't know if this is an improvement however.

```
from intspan import intspan

w1 = (3,8)
w2 = (5,11)
w3 = (20,30)

lo = 2
hi = 55

comp = intspan.from_ranges([w1,w2,w3]).complement(low=lo,high=hi)


idle_time = sum(map(lambda x: x[1]+1 - x[0], comp.ranges()))
print(idle_time)
```

This gives a total idle time as 34.

Comment: Excellent -- thank you for pointing me at this. Would you happen to know of a similar complement method that would operate on datetimes? In particular, if I wanted to extend this to continuous time and not simply the integers. This is very helpful, though!

Comment: As I think about it, I suppose there will be some finite granularity of time (seconds probably) that I could convert to an integer if push came to shove. With that, I'll accept this; thank you again!

Comment: Thank you, glad this was of some help. I suppose you could get the datetime timestamps (I think they are in millisecs) and get the compliment and convert that back into secs, mins or hours whichever you need.